# Puppet server multiple SSL certificates?

Tags: networking, ssl, puppet, docker

I have puppet server setup as part of a docker-composition.

I have nodes inside the composition which connect directly to the container. This works fine because the Puppet master automatically created an SSL certificate using its local name *(only available within the docker composition)* in a format similar to:

```
puppet.upgrades.jjk32jl.svc.dockerapp.io
```

I also have external nodes which aren't part of the composition which need to connect via an external url `upgrades.myorg.com`.

When I try to connect with outside nodes I get:

> Error: Could not request certificate: Server hostname
>   'puppet.upgrades.jjk32jl.svc.dockerapp.io' did not match server
>   certificate; expected one of
>   upgrades.myorg.com,
>   DNS:puppet,
>   DNS:upgrades.myorg.com

Can I set up a second certficate for dealing with external nodes (or use an alt-name) to deal with this situation? Or will I need to redirect internal communications between nodes to connect from the outside at `upgrades.myorg.com`?

---

*Update:*

I've added several alt-names to my master cert it now looks like this when I use `puppet cert -la`:

> "puppet.c9039f55-d345-45d1-a8bd-8fec89481559.local.dockerapp.io" (SHA256)
>   4B:A6:1F:C6:EA:8E:69:17:E3:43:C6:AE:A1:AE:BB:7B:9A:4F:09:5C:6F:92:BD:E7:C8:56:43:D8:03:12:59:
>   58 (alt names: "DNS:puppet",
>   "DNS:puppet-1.upgrades.fdafdafda.cont.dockerapp.io",
>   "DNS:puppet.c9039f55-d345-45d1-a8bd-8fec89481559.local.dockerapp.io",
>   "DNS:puppet.upgrades.jjk32jl.svc.dockerapp.io")

`puppet.upgrades.jjk32jl.svc.dockerapp.io` is listed as an alt-name but I get:

> Error: Could not request certificate: Server hostname
>   'puppet.upgrades.jjk32jl.svc.dockerapp.io' did not match server
>   certificate; expected one of
>   puppet.64b21c37-fa14-4406-b931-5add61cf582e.local.dockerapp.io,
>   DNS:puppet,
>   DNS:puppet.64b21c37-fa14-4406-b931-5add61cf582e.local.dockerapp.io

This is confusing because `puppet.64b21c37-fa14-4406-b931-5add61cf582e.local.dockerapp.io` isn't mentioned as an alt-name on the master certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way to handle this would be to add another alt name. You'd do this by setting the `dns_alt_names` option, then following the procedure to regenerate the master's certificate (adding the new names) that's listed in the documentation for the alt names option [here](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/configuration.html#dnsaltnames).

Comment: Sorry I marked correct too quickly. Unfortunately still having the same issue even with alt-name. Have updated question. Thanks for your help

Comment: It ended up being that the container name had changed and I had to add the new name again. So this answer did work. My mistake. All the best.